# How do I import node crypto into my Angular 11 components?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement a blockchain system in my angular application. And I've created a typescript file with the class implementation and crypto import statement.

```
import * as crypto from 'crypto';

class Blockchain {//blockchain code here}
```

However when I import this class into my angular components. I get this compile-time error 'Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '...'';

I'm using
Angular 12
node v16.3.0
typescript v4.1.5

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Usage of default `crypto` from Node.js:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
```

Demo at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cndtza?file=src/app/app.component.tshttps://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cndtza?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

**Official documentation:** https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I want to use the buit-in crypto module from node. Not import a third party like "crypto-js". Do you have any ideas how I can use the built-in module with-in my angular application?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that. Now check the updated answer. It's working. @NyanziAshraf

Comment: I'm still getting the same error as before "Error: ./src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\Development\GitHub\fuertes\src\app'"

Comment: Can you update the Node.js version to 15.12.0?
And after that Angular update?

Comment: Angular CLI: 11.1.0
Node: 15.12.0
OS: win32 x64

Comment: I get the same error every time I try to run or build my app. I appreciate your suggestions. I've been looking for a solution to this and haven't found anything conclusive.

Comment: I've also tried "import * as crypto from 'crypto'" and "import crypto from 'crypto'"

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'll still suggest you follow my answer.

Comment: Do you have any knowledge about Ethereum DApps in Angular?

Comment: No. I've just heard from you.

Comment: I know it's been a while since I asked but do you have any new suggestions for me to try.